# ¿Cómo poner en mayúsculas el primer carácter de una cadena en Android?

Tags: java, android, string

Necesito capitalizar una cadena en *Java* en *Android*

Normalmente uso:

```
public static String ucFirst(String str) {
    if (str.isEmpty()) {
        return str;            
    } else {
        return Character.toUpperCase(str.charAt(0)) + str.substring(1); 
    }
}


String ciudad = ucFirst("barcelona") //Barcelona
```

¿Hay una función en Java o librería que desconozco, para poner en mayúsculas minúsculas etc...?

Comment: Recuerdo que hasta Java 6 o 7 (HotSpot) había un leak de memoria al utilizar `String#substring` por contar con una implementación que permitía "buen rendimiento" y eso fue parchado en la siguiente versión del JDK /7 u 8). No sé si en Dalvik también sucede algo similar, sería bueno revisar su implementación.

Comment: Podrías usar el atributo que te ofrece el editText : android:inputType="textCapSentences"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yo entiendo que no existe tal función en Java nativo.

Dado que es algo tan simple como lo que mencionas en tu algoritmo, no sé si vale la pena depender de una biblioteca o similar para hacer eso. La implementación que se me ocurría a mí en particular es muy similar a la tuya. Solo que es utilizando `substring` y contemplando además la cadena nula. Más o menos lo siguiente:

```
public static String ucFirst(String str) {
    if (str == null || str.isEmpty()) return str;            
    else return str.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + str.substring(1); 
}
```

Espero sirva la respuesta.

Saludos.

Answer (score 3):

Para complementar la respuesta de @hdlopez, este proceso debería ser muy sencillo, lo más común sería esta función (la cual incluye una validación) en donde requiramos cambiar la primera letra a mayúsculas :

```
public static String ucFirst(String str) {
  if (str == null || str.isEmpty()) {
    return "";            
  } else {
    return str.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + str.substring(1); 
  }
}
```

Android esta procurando no usar las librerías Apache, tal como ocurrió con la clase Http y librerías externas para realizar esto no veo como opción para algo tan sencillo.

Otra opción para asegurar siempre tener el primer carácter en mayúscula y los demás en minúsculas es:

```
public static String ucFirst(String str) {
  if (str == null || str.isEmpty()) {
    return "";            
  } else {
    return  Character.toUpperCase(str.charAt(0)) + str.substring(1, str.length()).toLowerCase();
  }
}
```

Ejemplo:

```
String ciudad = ucFirst("barcElonA");
```

el valor de ciudad sería : `Barcelona`

Existen varias respuestas en Stackoverflow sobre este tema:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15259774/capitalise-first-letter-in-string-android

Answer (score 2):

[StringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) de Apache Commons Lang tiene un método llamado [`capitalize(String)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#capitalize(java.lang.String)) que hace exactamente eso. También tiene muchos otros métodos, <strike>tendrías que evaluar si se justifica agregar 2MB adicionales al APK.</strike>. Agrega unos 400KB a tu apk.

Si quieres hacerlo en una sola linea, puedes recurrir a algo así, que no tiene el if, y es mas fácil de leer:

```
String resultado = cadena.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + cadena.substring(1);
```

Pero este método probablemente es menos eficiente que el de tu ejemplo.

Tener en cuenta que si la cadena esta vacía/nula habrá que manejar una excepción. O usar un enfoque defensivo que incluya una validación por null/vació antes de ejecutar la sentencia, dependerá de caso de uso y agregarlo ya lo quita de una sola linea.

Comment: Para hacerlo en una línea se debe de estar seguro de que la cadena sea diferente de null y tenga por lo menos un elemento. Sino el substring fallará. O usar el operador "?"

Answer (score 2):

No creo que sea recomendado incluir una librería únicamente para capitalizar debido a que el proceso es bastante sencillo, pero tenemos esto:

```
String texto = "hola mundo";
```

> Sin librería, utilizando [String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) y [Character](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html).

```
texto = Character.toUpperCase(texto.charAt(0)) + texto.substring(1,texto.length());
```

> Sin librería, con lambdas (Java 8) [[Fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33352677/convert-first-character-of-string-to-uppercase-using-java-8-lambdas-only)]

```
texto = IntStream.concat(IntStream.of(texto.codePointAt(0)).map(Character::toUpperCase), texto.codePoints().skip(1) ).collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append).toString();
```

> Con librería, [Apache Commons Lang - WordUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) [ [**API**](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/WordUtils.html) ]

```
texto = WordUtils.capitalize(texto);
```

> El método capitalize(...) de StringUtils está basado en el mismo algoritmo que el de WordUtils.

```
texto = StringUtils.capitalize(texto);
```

Answer (score 0):

hice una respuesta parecida y me dieron está respuesta. me funcionó perfecto.

```
public static String convierte(String string) {
    if (string == null) {
        return null;
    }
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(string," ");
    while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
        String ne = (String)st.nextElement();
        if (ne.length()>0) {
            builder.append(ne.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase());
            builder.append(ne.substring(1).toLowerCase()); //agregado
            builder.append(' ');
        }
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```