# Primera letra en mayúsculas en Java

Tags: java, string

Tengo una duda muy sencilla que no se si se puede hacer como yo pienso, y siento si la duda es demasiado obvia para ustedes, estoy comenzando a programar.

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
String nombre;

System.out.println("Nombre:");
nombre=in.nextLine();
```

Hay alguna manera de que al recoger nombre, lo transforme automáticamente con la primera letra en mayúsculas y las demás en minúsculas?

De manera que si yo introduzco `aLberTo`, en realidad el programa recoja `Alberto`.

Saludos y gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola Leopard56., te saludo y te doy la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**,  saludos!

Comment: Gracias por las respuestas, mi pregunta iba más indicada a si se podía hacer la transformación directamente en la línea nombre=in.nextLine(); Pero por lo visto veo que hay que guardar el resultado e imprimirlo en otra variable.

Comment: Lo que comentas se puede realizar, puedes usar un método, y llamar dentro del método in.nextLine()  edité mi respuesta @Leopard56

Answer (score 5):

Esta es una forma rápida, obteniendo el carácter en la primera posición usando el método [**charAt()**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt(int)) y convirtiéndolo a mayúsculas mediante [**toUpperCase()**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toUpperCase()) :

```
nombre.toUpperCase().charAt(0)
```

este valor lo concatenas a el valor de la cadena original, eliminando el primer carácter, que es el que previamente convertiste a mayúscula, usando el método [**substring()**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)) :

```
nombre.substring(1, nombre.length())  //Elimina el primer carácter.
```

---

Este sería un ejemplo:

```
String nombre = "leopard56";
String resultado = nombre.toUpperCase().charAt(0) + nombre.substring(1, nombre.length()).toLowerCase();
System.out.println("resultado : " + resultado );
```

la salida sería:

```
resultado : Leopard56
```

---

Para realizar la transformación directamente en la linea,

```
nombre=in.nextLine();
```

puedes usar un método;

```
public static String toMayusculas(String valor) {
    if (valor == null || valor.isEmpty()) {
        return valor;
    } else {       
        return  valor.toUpperCase().charAt(0) + valor.substring(1, valor.length()).toLowerCase();
    }
}
```

y llamarlo antes de almacenar el valor

```
nombre = toMayusculas(in.nextLine());
```

Answer (score 2):

Basandome en esta respuesta del sitio:

> [¿Cómo poner en mayúsculas el primer carácter de una cadena en Android?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/10393/c%C3%B3mo-poner-en-may%C3%BAsculas-el-primer-car%C3%A1cter-de-una-cadena-en-android)

Adaptando un poco la respuesta, tu código quedaria de la siguiente manera:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String nombre;

    System.out.println("Nombre:");
    nombre = ucFirst(in.nextLine());
    System.out.println("Nombre: " + nombre);
}

public static String ucFirst(String str) {
    if (str == null || str.isEmpty()) {
        return str;
    } else {
        //La primera letra en mayuscula y las demas en minuscula.
        return str.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + str.substring(1).toLowerCase();
    }
}
```

Salida en consola:

> Nombre:
>   aLberTO
>   Nombre: Alberto

Answer (score 2):

lo que podrías hacer es lo siguiente:

Primero vas a crear una nueva variable para almacenar el nombre,

```
String nombreNuevo;
```

Después vas a utilizar los métodos substring, toUpperCase y toLowerCase.

- **Substring** es para extraer un número determinado de letras de una palabra.
- **toUpperCase** es para convertir un texto en mayúsculas.
- **toLowerCase** es para convertir un texto en minúsculas.

Entonces lo que haremos es lo siguiente:

```
nombreNuevo = nombre.substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + nombre.substring(1).toLowerCase();
```

`nombre.substring(0,1)` nos servirá para sacar la primera letra de la palabra y al aplicar `toUpperCase` la convertiremos en mayúscula.

`nombre.substring(1)` nos va a sacar el resto de las letras omitiendo la primera, y en seguida colocamos el `toUpperCase` para volver el resto de las letras en minúsculas y listo.

Answer (score 2):

Aunque entiendo que lo que se busca es implementar uno mismo el código considero importante mencionar que hay librerías (jars) que evitan el codificar uno mismo este tipo de rutinas.

Por ejemplo tenemos **commons-lang3** (https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) que cuenta con la clase StringUtils.
Mediante ella podemos programar lo solicitado usando los métodos estáticos de esta clase.

**StringUtils.capitalize**. Transforma la primer letra a mayúscula.

**StringUtils.lowerCase**.  Transforma una cadena a minúscula.

El ejemplo al utilizarlos es:

```
public class Ejemplo {

   public static void main( String[] args)
   {
      String texto = "aLberTO";


      System.out.println( StringUtils.capitalize(StringUtils.lowerCase(texto) ) );
   }
}
```

Notese que si la variable texto fuera nula los métodos no generarían una Excepción si no que devolverían nulo lo que nos evita generar mucha lógica de validación para evitar el NullPointerException en un código más elaborado.